# Start Spark master on the IP instead of Hostname

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to set up a remote Spark 2.4.5 cluster on Ubuntu 18. After I start `./sbin/stat-master.sh` WebUI is available at `<INSTANCE-IP>:8080` but it shows "Spark Master at spark://spark-master:7077" where `spark-master` is my hostname on the remote machine.

I'm able to start a worker with `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://spark-master:7077` only, but `<INSTANCE-IP>:4040` doesn't work. When I try `./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://<INSTANCE-IP>:7077` I can see the process but the worker is not visible in WebUI.

As a result, I can not connect to the cluster from my local machine with `spark-shell --master spark://<INSTANCE-IP>:7077`. The error is:

`StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master <INSTANCE-IP>:7077`

Comment: Seems like you have multiple network interfaces on the master, and the IP address your worker knows as `spark-master` is not `<INSTANCE-IP>`. So you may need to check which of the master's IP addresses is network-reachable from the workers and use that one. It should not make a difference whether you use the IP address or the host name, assuming the host name points to that IP address.

Comment: thank you @ernest_k I have it up and running after some changes in the hosts file and spark-env.sh